Why does the Docker plugin disappear from the sidebar in VS Code when I connect to the server remotely?
ssh docker plugin disappear
If I don't use VS Code's remote connection, the Docker plugin appears in the sidebar as expected. However, when I connect remotely, the Docker plugin disappears from the sidebar. Every time, I have to manually uninstall it and then reinstall it on the SSH server. How can I resolve this issue?
I expect the Docker plugin to appear in the sidebar when I connect to the remote server.

Docker extension needs to be installed on the machine your are using for developping. If it is on your local host, then it means that is installed on your computer. If you connect to a remote host, then it needs to be installed.
